# Use maven-publish to publish Android apk and aar with build variant (Android Gradle plugin 4.0)

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, maven-publish

I'm trying to follow https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin to publish library (aar) module and application (apk) module to Maven repository (`maven-publish` plugin). I'm using Kotlin Gradle kts instead of Grovy.

Sample publish in Grovy (from link above)

```
publishing {
    publications {
        paidRelease(MavenPublication) {
          // The following applies a component to this publication
          // which results in publishing an app bundle.
          from components.paidRelease_aab

          groupId = 'com.example.MyApp'
          artifactId = 'paid-release-aab'
          version = '1.0'
        }
        paidDebug(MavenPublication) {
          // The following applies a component to this publication
          // which results in publishing APKs in a ZIP file.
          from components.paidDebug_apk

          groupId = 'com.example.MyApp'
          artifactId = 'paid-debug-apks'
          version = '1.0'
        }
    }
}
```

My kotlin dls publishing code for app module

```
publications {
    create<MavenPublication>("mastercardMavenApk") {
        groupId = ProjectInfo.groupId
        artifactId = ProjectInfo.artifactId
        version = ProjectInfo.nexusVersion + if (useReleaseRepo) "" else "-SNAPSHOT"

        from(components["mastercardDebug_apk"])
    }
}
```

where `mastercardDebug` is one of my `Active Build Variant`

I always have below error:

```
SoftwareComponentInternal with name 'mastercardDebug_apk' not found
```

What should be the correct way to use `maven-publish` plugin for Android project (support both aar and apk module)?

Answer (score 0):

just use `print(components.names)` before  `from(components["mastercardDebug_apk"])`
to verify that the component exsists. maybe its just a typo